# Different array parse behaviour of x-www-form-urlencoded between ExpressJS and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, content-type, urlencode, body-parser

I use `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to send POST request to backend server. The post body as follow:

```
listing[pictures][files][][name]=9ADDD7B1-FCFF-4538-916A-1E63DFB43A72&
listing[pictures][files][][name]=EFFE67B2-5D41-4B74-A33E-5963F54FAEC7&
listing[pictures][files][][name]=BBC9CB38-FE01-4F1A-AE37-7ED71F4B2CB5
```

In backend server, if I use ruby on rails, the POST will be parsed as follow:

```
"pictures"=>{
    "files"=>[
        {"name"=>"9ADDD7B1-FCFF-4538-916A-1E63DFB43A72"}, 
        {"name"=>"EFFE67B2-5D41-4B74-A33E-5963F54FAEC7"}, 
        {"name"=>"BBC9CB38-FE01-4F1A-AE37-7ED71F4B2CB5"}
    ]
}
```

This result is what I expected to be.

But, If I use nodeJS `express` and `body-parser`:

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The POST will be parsed as follow:

```
"pictures"=>{
    "files"=>[
        "name"=>[
            "9ADDD7B1-FCFF-4538-916A-1E63DFB43A72", 
            "EFFE67B2-5D41-4B74-A33E-5963F54FAEC7", 
            "BBC9CB38-FE01-4F1A-AE37-7ED71F4B2CB5"
        ]
    ]
}
```

So, my question is how can I get the same POST result in nodeJS?

Comment: try to use `JSON.parse` in rails code

Comment: I mean, in rails the result is right, but in nodeJS body-parser the result is wrong.